# List Selection Listener valuechanged fired more than 2 times

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I add listselectionlistener when i clicked on a tab

```
table1 = new ListSelectionListener()
{
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
  {
    action(e);
  }
};
ListSelectionModel SM = table1A.getSelectionModel();
SM.addListSelectionListener(table1);
SM = table1B.getSelectionModel();
SM.addListSelectionListener(table1);
```

When i clicked on the row of the table, the action(e) function fired many times.

```
private void action(ListSelectionEvent e)
{
  ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

  if (lsm.getValueIsAdjusting())
  {
   // nothing
  }
  else
  {
   // my action here
  }
}
```

The action(e) should fired twice, once is when mouse clicked, once is when mouse release. I had use the getValueIsAdjusting() to counter the mouse click, so my action should be run once. But, my action run many times. i can see this because i need to put a busy dialog inside my action.

Comment: I think you are thinking of a `MouseListener`. `ListSelectionListener`s listen for changes to what is selected, not mouse clicks and releases. These can be very different things.

Comment: Well `ListSelectionModel SM = table1A.getSelectionModel();
SM.addListSelectionListener(table1); SM = table1B.getSelectionModel(); SM.addListSelectionListener(table1);` Does seem to be adding the listener twice!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set "value is Adjusting" to  true.

```
 SM.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
```

Please rename SM to sM because a java attribute should be begin with small letter.(Java Convention)

Comment: Where i need to set this?

Comment: Under ListSelectionModel SM = table1A.getSelectionModel();